# Mongoose Disconnect/reconnect Issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am currently using mongoose@4.0.4, whenever I manually disconnect MongoDb, mongoose  disconnect/reconnect event are not fired corrected, reconnect event is fired and disconnect is not being fired every time the MongoDb  is disconnect/started manually. My problem is to handle MongoDb connect and disconnected status so that for every request made to server I would see the status of the MongoDb connection/disconnection and send appropriate response(may be 500 code) because the request hangs up in middle if MongoDb is not connected.
To see if this was the version issue I stated version 3.8.x and went to 4.0.4 to see where the events are fired properly. I was able to catch reconnect event from version 4.0.x but not the disconnect event.
Basically wanted to know which version i can use where connect/disconnect events are fired properly or way to handle the issue.

below is the code handle events

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
var connected;
db.on('open', function (ref) {
    connected = true;
    console.log('open connection to mongo server.');
});

db.on('connected', function (ref) {
    global.mongo_conn=true;
    console.log('Connected connection to mongo server.');
});

db.on('disconnected', function (ref) {
    connected = false;
    console.log('disconnected connection.');
});
db.on('disconnect', function (err) {
    console.log('Error...disconnect', err);
});
db.on('connecting', function (ref) {
    connected = false;
    console.log('connecting.');
});

db.on('close', function (ref) {
    global.mongo_conn=false;
    console.log('close connection.');
    connect();
});

db.on('error', function (ref) {
    connected = false;
    console.log('Error connection.');
    //mongoose.disconnect();
    global.mongo_conn=false;
});

db.on('reconnected', function () {
    global.mongo_conn=true;
    console.log('MongoDB reconnected!');
});
db.on('reconnecting', function () {
    global.mongo_conn=true;
    console.log('reconnecting!');
});
function connect() {
    mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, opts);
}

connect();
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to catch the various events?

Comment: Finally I posted it on GitHub mongoose bug list, It will be released Next Version of MongoDB see here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3183.

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoose.connect(url, 
   {
      server: { 
         auto_reconnect: true,
         reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
         reconnectInterval: 1000,
         socketOptions: {keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000}
      } 
   }
);
```

Comment: Some words of explanation usually are appreciated on stack overflow.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).